# Radial velocity of two moving targets

Tags: radar, range-detector, space, velocity

The radial velocity is the velocity which is in the direction of the connecting line.

I would like to find the Doppler frequency of two moving targets, but as you know, this frequency only shows me the velocity in terms of the radial velocity. Here is the picture of two moving targets and the radial velocities they have. I am trying to find the resultant radial velocity which can be noted as Vrad1 + Vrad2 because they are oncoming. Can someone help me to find it? I am stuck.

Note: I should find the resultant radial velocity in terms of O1, O2, V1 and V2.

Graphic of two moving targets:

[image: Graphic of two moving targets]

Comment: This question belongs on Math Stackexchange.

Comment: This question has already been posted by the OP on Math.SE. Therefore migrating it would create a duplicate - bad. It is also off-topic here - bad. But people have spent time writing answers & deleting the question would also delete their answers = wasted time - bad. I don't see a good option for this situation. || It's a good example of why not to duplicate questions on multiple SE sites. || Best option is probably if the answer writers add their answers to the OP's question on Math.SE and *then* we delete this one here. Any other suggestions?

Comment: please delete your Math.SE question, so that this one can be migrated there in its place

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a vector \$R\$ that points *in the direction of* radial velocity, i.e. from one object to another. That vector is the difference between the positions of the two objects: \$R=O_2-O_1=(X_T,Y_T)-(X_R,Y_R)\$. This particular one is from radar to the target.
2. Normalize that vector: divide both its components by its length. Let's call this vector \$R_N\$ for Radial Normalized: \$R_N=R/|R|\$. The notation \$|R|\$ denotes the 2-norm of the vector, i.e. its euclidean length. *R* has unit length (1.0). When talking about vectors, unit means "of length 1".
3. Project each of the two velocities onto \$R_N\$. Since \$R_N\$ is a unit vector, the projection will retain proper scaling. Projection is done as a dot product "\$\cdot\$". So, you'll have \$|Vrad_1|=V_r\cdot R_N\$ and \$|Vrad_2|=V_t\cdot R_N\$.
4. The radial velocity is then the *difference* between the radial velocities of the radar and the target: \$V_rad=Vrad_2-Vrad_1\$.

These calculations are most straightforward to do using [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download).

Comment: O2 and O1 are angles sir not the position. Won't we use that angles?

Comment: @SpiderMan93 I've used O1 and O2 to mean positions of the radar and the target, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Homework. Only guidance is available.

Let's call the placement vectors of your objects A and B. A is the place (=the coordinates) of the leftmost one in your image. B is the placement of the rightmost object.

The righmost object as seen by the leftmost one has relative placement vector B-A.

The rightmost object moves in relative to the leftmost object with velocity vector (d/dt)(B-A) = (dB/dt)-(dA/dt) = (Vt - Vr) where Vt and Vr are vectors.

You must find which part of this is in parallel with the connection line between the objects. In elementary vector algebra you simply calculate the scalar product of (Vt-Vr) and the unit vector from the leftmost object to the rightmost. That's the wanted velocity.

Hopefully you can recall the unit vector which points from the leftmost object to the rightmost one is (B-A)/absolutevalue(B-A).

The guidance stops here.